# Message "Não encontrou uma resposta?" links to es-SO instead of pt-SO

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, portuguese-stack-overflow

Today I've started seeing the following ad:

[image: Não encontrou uma resposta? Pergunte em Stack Overflow em Português.]

You can translate this message as:

*Did you not find an answer? Ask in Portuguese Stack Overflow.*

The problem is that the message links to the Spanish SO and not to the Portuguese version.

Original message:

> Não encontrou uma resposta? [Pergunte em Stack Overflow em Português.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?fromen=01a6efc01238e)

Comment: This shouldn't be closed just because it is fixed. The "can no longer be reproduced" close reason is for bugs that literally can't ever return because of major or fundamental changes, like CRT burn-in for a system that has been fully transitioned to LCD's. This error could return due to a bad merge or fat finger.

Comment: Voted to reopen. This question is marked as [meta-tag:status-completed], meaning that no one in SO will consider this in their backlog of bugs. No need to close/delete questions like that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry about that, it's fixed now. *Be careful when copy-pasting, kids!*

Comment: Ow! That was fast! (it's already live)

Comment: This post was noticed quickly by someone who then pinged me in the team chat, and these links are site settings that can be changed on the fly (no need to recompile anything).