# Banner "Não encontrou uma resposta?" goes to Spanish SO (Again)

Tags: bug, status-completed, portuguese-stack-overflow, international-sites

Yes, it has been reported before [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343775/6195472), back in February 2017. Marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). So I'm reporting it again.

This banner is redirecting to `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?utm=soensept&fromen=3182044011cfd` and that link is the Spanish Stack Overflow, and not the Portuguese SO.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was an invalid default site setting, which originated from a wrong default value in the code. I've fixed the site setting, so the link should already be correct. I've also fixed the invalid default so this shouldn't happen again.